# Invite to play app request on Facebook using php but without using javascript

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

```
FB.ui({
        method: 'apprequests',
        title: 'abc!',
        to: friendID,
        message: 'I play abc! Can you beat me?',
},fbCallback);
```

this works great on  javascript but how these thing is implemented in php. I tried this-

```
<?php 
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$response = $facebook->api(
                            '/'.$fid.'/apprequests', 
                            'POST', array(
                                      'title' => 'Musical Quiz!',   
                                      'message' => 'I just play musical quiz! Can you beat me?.',                                  
                                      'access_token' => $access_token
                           )); 

?>
```

but it request only those user who already played that game. Is there any way, through which i can invite to play any of my facebook friends?